# Draw rounded corner line using canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw rounded corner line using canvas. Like eg:

[image]

```
public class MyView extends View {

 Paint paint;
 Path path;

 public MyView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  init();
 }

 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  init();
 }

 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  init();
 }

 private void init() {
  paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

  path = new Path();
  path.moveTo(50, 50);
  path.lineTo(50, 500);
  path.lineTo(200, 500);
  path.lineTo(200, 300);
  path.lineTo(350, 300);

  float radius = 50.0f;

  CornerPathEffect cornerPathEffect =
    new CornerPathEffect(radius);

  paint.setPathEffect(cornerPathEffect);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

 }

}
```

I am able to draw corner line using paint as shown above, but not from the canvas.

I tried **canvas.drawLine()** and **canvas.drawArc()** to achieve the same result but failed to do that.

Can somebody help me to solve the issue?

Comment: `"but not from the canvas."` what do you mean by that? whats wrong with `canvas.drawPath(path, paint);`?

Comment: and? whats wrong with `canvas.drawPath(path, paint);`?

Comment: @pskink : I have implemented my application line drawing with the help of canvas.drawLine(), so I want to continue my canvas.drawLine() logic. I want the solution where i have to do minimal changes.

Comment: does `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)` work or not? why do you want to make your code complex if you can just use `CornerPathEffect` instead?

Comment: I tried this on my POC where it works but don't want to integrate this into my app.

Comment: aha, good luck then

Comment: "i want to sort my list of objects - i know i cam use `Collections#sort(List<T> list)` but i dont want it - how can i sort it on my own?" - your approach it like the same - i have no idea why not to use `CornerPathEffect` in that case...

Comment: @pskink: I am integrating CornerPathEffect in my app, hope so it will work.